# what's the consequence of registering the same NSURLProtocol more than once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlprotocol

I'm building a component that supports the enabling / disabling of a feature that requires an NSURLProtocol.

in the `isEnabled` setter I do:

```
- (void)setIsEnabled:(BOOL)isEnabled {
    _isEnabled = isEnabled;
    if (isEnabled) {
       [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyURLProtocol class]];
   } else {
       [NSURLProtocol unregisterClass:[MyURLProtocol class]];
   }
}
```

The URL loading system goes through the registered protocols in the order of registration, so I'm wondering what will be the consequence of registering the same protocol more than once as a result of this setter being fired multiple times? will it just get bumped to the top of the list ? or will this have further / other consequences ?

Other considerations:

- I'm aware of the possibility to unregister every time before I
  register the protocol, but would like to avoid it if I can.
- The component at hand is an SDK, not an app - so I can not register my
  protocol on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...`

Further to reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlprotocol) and the great [hipsters notes](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/), I couldn't find any relevant information, so any insight is appreciated !

Comment: Not sure how your protocol subclasses are organized, but remember that these can respond to `canInitWithRequest:`.  Have that answer the enabled state.

Comment: Since you're also unregistering, I don't see issues with your code